# Как двигать элементы в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Как двигать элементы мышкой в Android studio[image: Я мышкой двигаю элемент на определенное место, когда отпускаю ЛКМ, то элемент возвращается на первоначальное место]

Comment: Хватать и тянуть, не?

Comment: Эникейщик прав, нужно хватать и тянуть

Comment: если я хватаю и тяну, то когда я отпускаю лкм, оно возвращается на первоначальное место положения

Comment: Я понял, выросло новое поколение прогеров, которое кодирует только в стиле `drag-n-drop` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эникейщик дело говорит, но прежде чем у вас получится, вам нужно изучить типы Layout-ов. Начните с [FrameLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/framelayout.php), [LinearLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/linearlayout.php) и [ConstraintLayout](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html). Как по мне самые ходовые, статейки конечно немного устарели, но достаточно понятны. И стоит изучать в том же порядке.

Ответ на ваш вопрос: использовать ConstraintLayout, но после запуска вашего приложения все View переместятся в левый верхний угол (для RTL в правый), так как они не будут иметь привязок.